# Android - map map is blank on one device, not others

Tags: android, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Hoping someone can help with this.  I have a map fragment in my Android app, but on one physical device (Android 11 with the Feb 2022 security update) it always comes up blank.  On another device (Android 8), and on Android 11 and Android 12 AVDs, the maps display just fine.  I'm not seeing anything in logcat (such as an authentication issue from an invalid key or lack of permission) it just...never renders.

Interestingly, it *does* respond to long-clicks (presses) with appropriate latitude/longitudes.  I'm just long-pressing blindly to get them.

For reference - my layout is:

```
    ...
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        xmlns:tools="http:`//schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/mfbMap"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ActFlightMap" />
    ....
```

The relevant manifest sections:

```
    <application ...>
        ...
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/GoogleMapsKey" />
    </application>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

And my main code:

```
class ActFlightMap : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback,
    OnMarkerClickListener, OnGlobalLayoutListener,  OnMapLongClickListener, CoroutineScope by MainScope() {
   ...
   public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.flightmap)

        val mf = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mfbMap) as SupportMapFragment?
        try {
            mf?.getMapAsync(this)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Log.e("MyAppTag", Objects.requireNonNull(ex.localizedMessage))
        }
        ...
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        val map = googleMap

        map.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID
        val settings = map.uiSettings
        settings.isCompassEnabled = false
        settings.isRotateGesturesEnabled = false
        settings.isScrollGesturesEnabled = true
        settings.isZoomControlsEnabled = false
        settings.isZoomGesturesEnabled = true

        map.setOnMapLongClickListener(this)
        ...
    }
```

In the above code, I can verify that onMapReady is in fact called and googleMap is non-null.  I can add elements to the map.  Long click (as mentioned above) works.  Nothing mentioning maps in the logcat.  I even get the little "press to center on your current location" icon.  The tiles just never draw on my Android 11 phone, but it all works flawlessly in both the emulators and on my older (Android 8) phone.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a theming issue.

When this theme is applied to the hosting activity (ActFlightMap, above), it doesn't work:

```
   <style name="MFBTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorBackground</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>
    </style>
```

But if I simply change the theme in the manifest to use @style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight, it works great on the devices that hadn't been working.

No idea what the problem is with the theme above, or why it only impacts some devices.